# How to avoid polling in Twilio?

Tags: python, macos, twilio, observer-pattern, polling

I would like to create a Twilio app in python that runs in the background on my mac osx desktop and performs an action whenever a new text message arrives. I'm only interested in processing the most recently received text message.

My current solution is a polling mechanism where I have an infinite loop and in the loop I call TwilioRestClient(...).messages.list() every single time and process the first message in the returned array. I sleep for 1 second in each iteration in order to avoid taxing the processor too much.

The current implementation usually works but sometimes lags at the TwilioRestClient(...).messages.list() call for multiple seconds. I'm assuming this is because I'm using the trial version of Twilio. However, any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. The other main issue is that the implementation is extremely wasteful. The app should really be sleeping for the vast majority of the time it is running and there should be brief spurts of activity when new messages arrive.

Here's the current implementation:

```
def run(self):
    last_message = self.get_most_recent_message_body().lower()
    self.is_running = True
    while self.is_running:
        message = self.get_most_recent_message_body().lower()
        if (message != last_message):
            last_message = message
            self.commander.execute(message)
            sleep(1);

def get_most_recent_message_body(self):
    messages = TwilioRestClient(self.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, self.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN).messages.list()
    most_recent_message = messages[0]
    return most_recent_message.body
```

I want the app to be as responsive as possible. The optimal solution would be some kind of Observer pattern or some kind of signal use where Twilio alerts my app to "wake up" whenever a new message arrives. Is there a way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I remember when I tried Twilio, it let you enter a URL that would be fetched whenever there was some kind of incoming event. If you can open a port and set up DynDNS or something, you might be able to have Twilio talk to your computer directly; otherwise, you might need to have some sort of server that you can connect to to receive notifications it receives from Twilio.

Comment: @icktoofay, yeah I guess that is the best way to do it. It seems ugly to need a proxy server like that doesn't do anything but pass the text on, but I guess it makes sense because then I can use a web socket. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely do that without polling. Let me explain.

When you buy a number with Twilio you can set two URLs that point to an application that you build, one for voice and one for messaging. Then, when Twilio receives a call or a text message it will make an HTTP request (a webhook) to the url you set with the details of the call or the message. Your application can respond with some XML (called TwiML) to tell Twilio what to do with the message or call.

I'm guessing you're writing a python application as you tagged this question with Python. Here's a quick guide to [getting started receiving SMS messages with Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/hello-monkey).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and for the link you provided. I guess the main issue is that I want the program to directly run on my desktop computer without making my desktop into a server. It's ugly, but I think the best solution may be to do as was suggested by one of the comments above and have a proxy server running on Heroku or something that I point Twilio to and then communicate between the server and my computer.

Comment: Have you considered something like http://ngrok.com to tunnel an external URL to your desktop so that you don't need a middle server?